# Add a record to an existing user

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

The goal is to add a record to a table called `Result`. If the `user(email)` does not exist the user `Table` it will create a new account and after that create the `Result` record.

```
user = User.where(:email => email)

if user.empty?
   User.create!(:email => email, :password => 'penita_pena')
   new_user = User.last
   new_user.results.create!(patient: patient, gender: gender, insurance_plan: insurance_plan, age: age)
else
  user.results.create!(patient: patient, gender: gender, insurance_plan: insurance_plan, age: age)
end
```

The first part works just fine, but after the `else` I'm getting the following error:

```
undefined method `results' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_User:0x007fe8d5ff2a10>
```

I thought `user` was holding the user object who match the email. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
User.find_by(email: email).
```

You are doing a search over all Users with that email, so user is not a single User object, but a list of objects. Another way would be

```
User.where(email: email).first.
```

A nicer way of writing the same code is:

```
user = User.find_or_create_by!(email: email) do |user|
  user.password = 'penita_pena'
end
user.results.create!(...)
```

Comment: Hi thanks Hampei, the thing with find_or_create_by! is that I need to send a different email notifications to users (current and new). And I do not know how can I make that happen with that method.

Comment: I read the documentation, I understood the block is in charge of creating the User. Cool, thanks again Hampei.